# x86 asm crashing application

Tags: c, x86

```
char program[3] = { 0x6a,  0x0a, 0xC3 }; //push 10; ret;
char (*p)(void) = program;
printf("char = %c \n", p());
```

This code crashes. Why?

The following code works ok:

```
char program[3] = { 0x90,  0x90, 0xC3 }; //nop; nop; ret
void (*p)(void) = program;
p();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should understand that you cannot just "do things" in assembly and expect it to work. There is something called an Application Binary Interface with specifies how programs across the operating system and indeed inside your code are to behave.

For example, in C on most x86-32 platforms, one common rule is that `eax` should contain the return value. There will also be a set of values that are pushed onto the stack (called the stack frame for a function). Another is that certain registers need to be preserved whilst others (sometimes called scratch registers) can be left with your garbage in them.

In short, if you violate these rules, things go wrong and the OS tidies up for you. It really depends not only on your processor but your operating system; even linux and windows on `x64` are different, for example.

I should also add `char program` is not a program, it is a function inside an existing program.

Finally, `nop, nop, ret` does nothing. So you are fine to execute these instructions and return because you have in fact not done anything to the stack frame.

Comment: I don't know where I got the idea that return values were added to the stack from. Thanks

Comment: Input values are added to the stack; I'm guessing by your use of `nop` you're exploring the idea of a nop sled, a way to exploit functions that don't check sizes of parameters correctly, commonly called a buffer overflow...

Comment: No I was just showing that it wasn't an issue with the C code but the instructions themselves.

Comment: Ah fair enough... well, have a look at nop sleds - it's really clever. Will make you paranoid about checking sizes though...

Answer (score 5):

Because you need to cleanup your stack by popping from it.  Read more on the `ret` instruction - it will load cs:ip with values from the stack!

Comment: Technically only `retf` loads both CS and EIP (far return) - `retn` only pops EIP (and is what most assemblers will output for `ret` these days). Ignoring of course instructions such as `iret` which you rarely see in userspace).

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you learn about calling conventions. For 32-bit x86, a function that modifies the stack should look more like this (cdecl):

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp ; or ENTER instruction for the push+mov

; Function code!

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp ; or LEAVE instruction for the mov+pop
ret
```

The `mov esp, ebp` ensures your stack returns to the way it was at the beginning of the function, which means the return address is on the stack for `ret` to load and jump to.

Local variables in the function are placed on the stack (`sub esp, 0x4` would allocate space for one 32-bit variable, usable as `[esp + 0]`).

64-bit x86 (not Itanium) has its own calling convention. Then there's fastcall and such.

The [Wikipedia Article on x86 Calling Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) is worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 2):

```
char program[] = {
    0x55,              /* push %ebp */
    0x89, 0xe5,        /* mov %esp, %ebp */
    0x6a, 0x0a,        /* push $0xa */
    0x8b, 0x04, 0x24,  /* mov (%esp), %eax */
    0x89, 0xec,        /* mov %ebp, %esp */
    0x5d,              /* pop %ebp */
    0xc3,              /* ret */
};
```

That'll work*.  Your program crashes because you're messing up the stack layout.

* as long as `program` resides in an executable part of memory, which is not necessarily true, and you're running on x86-32 with the typical C calling convention

Answer (score 0):

And aside from cleaning up the stack, based on the intent(expecting output of 10) of your program...

```
char program[3] = { 0x6a,  0x0a, 0xC3 }; //push 10; ret;
char (*p)(void) = program;
printf("char = %c \n", p())
```

..., you shouldn't push 10, return value from functions are stored in AX(16 bit), EAX if 32 bit

If passing parameter is intended, cleaning up the stack depends on calling convention of function, if it is __fastcall (or pascal), it is the invoked routine that must do the cleanup; if it is C calling convention (_cdecl), it is the caller who should clean up the stack